# jqGrid with Virtual Scrolling not returning records in correct order

Tags: ajax, wcf, jqgrid

We're using a jqGrid 3.8.2 with virtual scrolling to scroll a list of records.  It works well if the user is scrolling through the list slowly.  As soon as the user grabs the scroll bar and quickly scrolls all the way to the bottom the records returned in the grid are completely out of order and sometimes duplicated.  The AJAX call we are making to get the records calls a WCF service that returns the records from a database to the AJAX callback in the jqGrid in which the data then gets loaded to the grid.  The database expects a page number which in turn indicates which page of records we want.

I am pretty sure the results are coming back in the wrong order due to timing of the AJAX calls.  Meaning the calls aren't always first in first out.  Newer calls are likely being returned back to the jqGrid before earlier calls.

Any thoughts on how to get this to work correctly?  Any steps that I could take to help get us going in the right direction?

If it helps, here is the js configuration:

```
PersonalListContactGridControl.GetGridConfig = function() {
    var jqGridConfig = {
        url: Common.AjaxService.serviceUrl + "/GetPersonalListContacts",
        datatype: "JSON",
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
        mtype: "POST",
        autowidth: true,
        height: PersonalListContactGridControl.Constants.Height,
        altRows: true,
        sortname: "LastName",
        viewrecords: true,
        emptyrecords: "",
        loadtext: '',
        multiselect: true,
        //sortorder: "desc",

        //- virtual scrolling:: 1 ON / 0 OFF
        loadonce: false, // SUPPORT FOR REBIND
        rowNum: PersonalListContactGridControl.Constants.GridPageSize,
        scroll: 1,

        gridview: true,

        //- column header text
        colNames: ['EndPointID',
            PersonalListContactGridControl.Constants.FirstNameColumnDisplayText,
            PersonalListContactGridControl.Constants.LastNameColumnDisplayText,
            PersonalListContactGridControl.Constants.EmailFaxColumnDisplayText,
            PersonalListContactGridControl.Constants.TypeColumnDisplayText],
        //- column specific definitions
        colModel: [
            { name: 'EndPointID', index: 'EndPointID', hidden: true },
            { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 155, align: 'left', editable: false, title: true,
              hidden: false, resizable: true, sortable: true, editoptions: { readonly: true },
              formatter: PersonalListContactGridControl.formatLink },
            { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 155, align: 'left', editable: false, title: true,
              hidden: false, resizable: true, sortable: true, editoptions: { readonly: true },
              formatter: PersonalListContactGridControl.formatLink },
            { name: 'EmailAddress', index: 'EmailAddress', width: 240, align: 'left', editable: false, title: true,
              hidden: false, resizable: true, sortable: true, editoptions: { readonly: true },
              formatter: PersonalListContactGridControl.formatEmailFax },
            { name: 'EndPointType', index: 'EndPointType', width: 60, align: 'left', editable: false, title: true,
              hidden: false, resizable: true, sortable: true,  editoptions: { readonly: true },
              formatter: PersonalListContactGridControl.formatType }
        ],

        //- jqGrid's "reader" ... the structure of the JSON/XML returned (Fiddler) must match this
        jsonReader: {
            root: "d.Contacts",
            total: function(obj) {
                return Math.ceil(obj.d.TotalRecords / PersonalListContactGridControl.Constants.GridPageSize);
            },
            records: function(obj) {
                return obj.d.TotalRecords;
            },
            id: 'EndPointID',
            repeatitems: false
        },

        serializeGridData: function(jqGridParms) {
            //alert(jqGridParms.page);
            return PersonalListContactGridControl.GetRequest(jqGridParms);
        },
        loadComplete: function(data) {
            if (data.d) {
                if (data.d.ResponseProperties.Success === false) {
                    if (data.d.ResponseProperties.ErrorMessage.indexOf('The List has been deleted') > -1) {
                        ManagePersonalList.OnPersonalListErrorHandler();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                var grid = PersonalListContactGridControl.Grid();
                if (data.d.Contacts == null || data.d.Contacts.length == 0) { // are there any records?
                    // check if row exists
                    if (!grid.getInd(-1)) {
                        if (PersonalListContactGridControl.SearchString == "") {
                            grid.addRowData(-1, { "FirstName": PersonalListContactGridControl.Constants.NoContactDisplayText });
                        }
                        else {
                            grid.addRowData(-1, { "FirstName": PersonalListContactGridControl.Constants.NoContactForSearchDisplayText });
                        }
                        grid.find('#-1 input').hide(); // takeout the selection checkbox
                    }
                    PersonalListGridControl.ToggleExportButton(false);
                }
                else {
                    if (PersonalListContactGridControl.Constants.dtoToSelectID != null) {
                        if (PersonalListContactGridControl.SelectContactById(PersonalListContactGridControl.Constants.dtoToSelectID, true))
                            PersonalListContactGridControl.Constants.dtoToSelectID = null;
                    }
                    PersonalListGridControl.ToggleExportButton(true);
                }
                // cache the return objects
                PersonalListContactGridControl.DTOS = PersonalListContactGridControl.DTOS.concat(data.d.Contacts);
                PersonalListContactGridControl.InitRows();
            }
        },
        loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Type: " + status + "; Response: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        },

        onCellSelect: function(rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
            if (iCol == 0)
                PersonalListContactGridControl.CheckItem();
            else
                PersonalListContactGridControl.SelectContactById(rowid);
        },

        onSelectRow: function(id, status) {
            if (!status) return;
        },
        onSelectAll: function() {
            var grid = PersonalListContactGridControl.Grid();
            var selections = new Array();
            selections = grid.getGridParam('selarrrow');
            if (selections[0] == -1) {
                //if -1, then no rows are available
                PersonalListContactGridControl.UpdateHeaderCount(0);
            }
            else {
                PersonalListContactGridControl.UpdateHeaderCount(selections.length);
                ManagePersonalList.OnSelectAllChanged(this, { Ids: selections });
            }
        }
    };

    return jqGridConfig;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your JSONReader to..

```
    jsonReader: {
        root: "d.Contacts",
        page: "d.currpage",
        total: "d.totalpages",
        records: "d.TotalRecords",
        id: 'EndPointId',
        repeatitems: false
    },
```

the d.totalpages and d.currpage should come back from the AJAX call